# Rendering a JComponent inside a wrapper class without exposing it

Tags: java, design-patterns, jtable, wrapper, jcomponent

I'm trying to create what is essentially a modified version of a `JTable`, call it `MyTable`, for which I explicitly define the API. My idea was to create `MyTable` as a wrapper for `JTable`, but suppose I want to show the underlying `JTable` on screen so that users can interact with it: How would I go about this? My first thought was to provide a getter for the JTable, but of course then I lose the safety of encapsulating it because someone can do `aMyTable.getJTable().someUndesirableAction()`. What is the best approach to take here?

Apologies if this is a silly question! Please feel free to tell me if I'm approaching this problem from the totally wrong angle, which I have a feeling I might be.

Comment: maybe a decorator like [`Collections.unmodifiableList(wrappedList)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html)

Comment: Does _interface_ mean API or UI? What API or UI element(s) are you trying to control? What is the underlying [*problem*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/163188)?

Comment: @trashgod API, sorry. I've edited my question to make that clear. At the moment, the most pressing thing is that I don't want people to have access to the table's models, renderers, or editors, but I guess I was hoping that there was a more general solution to this problem.

Comment: I'd look at [Bloch, *Effective Java*](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780137150021?portal=informit), Chapter 4. Classes and Interfaces, Item 17: Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it."

Comment: @trashgod Will do. Thanks so much for the tip!